# Saving a file to a network drive through Python?

Tags: python, file-permissions

I am saving a file in the following way:

```
 name = os.path.join('/mnt/logs', "Hello.txt")
    f = open(name, 'a')
```

and I have mounted a drive (mount -t cifs) to /mnt/logs.

The problem is, the file does show up in /mnt/logs on the raspbian OS system, but not on the drive.

I am executing the python file which includes this saving with sudo privileges in rc.local.

I thought it might be to do with permissions since only sudo touch worked to put a file on that system, but I am running the file in sudo so it doesn't make sense.

I also managed to put a file on the disk previously, but then I wasn't actually getting the data on the webapplication, so I had to change location where I opened the file and so on, and now it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: I also tried to give the python file different permissions... chmod 6775 and chmod u+s , neither of which made a change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it has to do with the command that starts the server. It seems to mount it temporarily, rather than permanently. Switching the Raspberry pi off seems to unmount the drive.